# How to handle gnome-settings-daemon memory leak?

Tags: fedora, gnome, desktop-environment

I recently moved to Fedora 21 x86 with Gnome 3 and have noticed that the gnome-settings-daemon has steadily increased to 50% of my system memory (8 of 16 gigs) in the last 7 days.

I haven't been able to identify any contributing factors to the situation and don't know how to restart it by itself. Restarting the gnome server seems to have no effect (i.e. alt+f2, r).

If there's a way to restart it until this is tracked down or what I can look for in this program to track it down that would be very helpful.

Comment: `Alt+F2, r` restarts the shell. `gnome-session-daemon` is a dependecy for `gnome-shell`, not the other way around. You'll have to either restart `gnome-session` (this will restart the daemon too) or restart the daemon only, e.g. something like `/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon --replace --debug > gsd.log` would enable debug mode and output to a file named `gsd.log`. Run `/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon --help-all` to see all possible options.

Comment: Excellent tip, I should have checked the program settings. I'll log for the next couple of days and see what I can spot, in the meanwhile restarting the service works as a tourniquet. The location of the executables were a bit different, but I tracked them down with rpm -ql gnome-settings-daemon.

Comment: Probably related to [this issue of gnome-settings-daemon](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/issues/64)